# Unmarshalling a non mandatory ENUM @XmlElement

Tags: java, soap, enums, cxf, unmarshalling

I have added some adapters for marshall/unmarshall enums for the XmlRootElement, it worked perfectly, but some of this enum elements can be null, so now, the @XmlJavaTypeAdapter enfonces the unmarshalling no matter if the field is not mandatory. Is there a way to set @XmlJavaTypeAdapter action only when @XmlElement(required = true)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not just handle null parameters in the unmarshal() and marshal() methods in adapter?

Comment: Oh lord, you are right... closing the question, thanks.